# Postgres: Expand JSON data to columns and rows

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table in SQL containing a column in JSON format.

I need for each row in this table to expand the JSON objects and values into new columns with the respective data included.

Example for the first row would be one new column named "rate" and its value would be "0.25", while for the second row other columns should be created named "from","to","fixed" and the respective values should be stored in two separate rows keeping the rest of the info identical as is in the query itself.

The complexity here is each row on the dataset has different information stored in the "Data Value" column (JSON data).

Is there any way I could use a query or any other method to do this?

Comment: Your query will need to generate a fixed set of columns, for *all* rows. The columns only depend on the query (and database schema), never on the data.

Comment: How do you want to handle the arrays where you have multiple data values per row?

Comment: Yes i would need like 10s of new columns probably based on the data included in the JSON.
Each row that does not have the specific object will show null.

In regards to the second comment I would want the specific row to be multiplied by the number of data values for each array so if an array has 2 values just duplicate the row, if it has more create a new row for each value.

Does that make sense?

Comment: No, you need to decide beforehand which columns you query, it cannot be dynamic depending on the data. If you really need that, fetch the JSON value and do post-processing in the application code.

Comment: I edited my post. this is somehow the required output. But arrays do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`jsonb_array_elements` table function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) to work with arrays. However, your data is extra challenging because you are storing a mix of objects and arrays-of-objects, try to avoid that if possible. So I'd first wrap the objects in an array using `jsonb_typeof` and `jsonb_build_array`:

```
SELECT
  *,
  jsonb_array_elements(CASE jsonb_typeof(pefd.value)
    WHEN 'array' THEN pefd.value
    WHEN 'object' THEN jsonb_build_array(pefd.value)
  --ELSE NULL
  END) AS obj
FROM
  port_expense_formula_data pefd;
```

or to access the `obj` properties:

```
SELECT
  *,
  (obj ->> 'rate')::float AS "rate",
 obj ->> 'from' AS "from",
 obj ->> 'to' AS "to",
 (obj ->> 'fixed')::int AS "fixed"
FROM
  port_expense_formula_data pefd,
  jsonb_array_elements(CASE jsonb_typeof(pefd.value)
    WHEN 'array' THEN pefd.value
    WHEN 'object' THEN jsonb_build_array(pefd.value)
  --ELSE NULL
  END) AS obj;
```

However, to extract JSON properties into columns, I recommend to use records via `jsonb_to_recordset` instead of `jsonb_array_elements`, which also lets you easily choose the column type:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  port_expense_formula_data pefd,
  jsonb_to_recordset(CASE jsonb_typeof(pefd.value)e)
    WHEN 'array' THEN pefd.value
    WHEN 'object' THEN jsonb_build_array(pefd.value)
  --ELSE NULL
  END) AS obj(
    "rate" float,
    "from" text,
    "to" text,
    "fixed" int
  );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the effort @Bergi! I will give it a shoot tomorrow and let you know if I got a result or not!

Answer (score 1):

First flatten the table using [jsonb_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) to unnest the JSON array and a [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) in order to produce a row per array element.

```sql
SELECT
 port.id                         as "Port ID",
 port.name                       as "Port Name",
 country.name                    as "Country",
 port_expense.id                 as "Port Expense ID",
 port_expense.name::text         as "Port Expense",
 terminal.id                     as "Terminal ID",
 terminal.name                   as "Terminal Name",
 berth.id                        as "Berth ID",
 berth.name                      as "Berth Name",
 port_expense_formula_data.name  as "Data Name",
 port_expense_formula_data.value as "Data Value"
  j->>'from'    as "From", 
  j->>'to'      as "To",
  j->>'unmoor'  as "Unmoor",
  j->>'var'     as "Var",
  j->>'tariff'  as "Tariff",
  j->>'rate'    as "Rate",
  j->>'lumpsum' as "Lumpsum",
  j->>'max'     as "Max",
  j->>'min'     as "Min",
  j->>'charge'  as "Charge",
  j->>'day'     as "Day",
  j->>'night'   as "Night" 
from <your joined tables here> 
cross join lateral 
  jsonb_array_elements(port_expense_formula_data.value::jsonb) j;
```

`cross join lateral` is the verbose syntax. It can be replaced by `, lateral` or - in the case of a set-returning function as above - just a comma.

You may simulate/experiment with this example:

```sql
with t(a, b, jdata) as 
(
 values
 (1, 2, '[{"x":10, "y":20}, {"x":110, "y":120}]'),
 (3, 4, '[{"x":11, "y":21}, {"x":111, "y":121, "z":221}]'),
 (5, 6, '[{"x":12, "y":22}, {"x":112, "y":122, "z":222}]'),
 (7, 8, '[{"x":13, "y":23}, {"x":113, "y":123}]')
)
select t.a, t.b, 
       j->>'x' as x, j->>'y' as y, j->>'z' as z
from t, jsonb_array_elements(t.jdata::jsonb) j;
```

Comment: I missed that some of the JSON values are arrays and other are not. @Bergi has got it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to differentiate whether jsonb column contains a single json or array of jsons. Therefore, I'd do something like:

```sql
WITH array_json as (
select * from port_expense_formula_data 
where jsonb_typeof(port_expense_formula_data.value::jsonb) = 'array'
), object_json as (
select * from port_expense_formula_data 
where jsonb_typeof(port_expense_formula_data.value::jsonb) = 'object'
)
SELECT
 port.id                         as "Port ID",
 port.name                       as "Port Name",
 country.name                    as "Country",
 port_expense.id                 as "Port Expense ID",
 port_expense.name::text         as "Port Expense",
 terminal.id                     as "Terminal ID",
 terminal.name                   as "Terminal Name",
 berth.id                        as "Berth ID",
 berth.name                      as "Berth Name",
 array_json.name  as "Data Name",
 array_json.value as "Data Value"
  j->>'from'    as "From", 
  j->>'to'      as "To",
  j->>'unmoor'  as "Unmoor",
  j->>'var'     as "Var",
  j->>'tariff'  as "Tariff",
  j->>'rate'    as "Rate",
  j->>'lumpsum' as "Lumpsum",
  j->>'max'     as "Max",
  j->>'min'     as "Min",
  j->>'charge'  as "Charge",
  j->>'day'     as "Day",
  j->>'night'   as "Night" 
from array_json, lateral 
  jsonb_array_elements(array_json.value::jsonb) j
UNION ALL
SELECT
 port.id                         as "Port ID",
 port.name                       as "Port Name",
 country.name                    as "Country",
 port_expense.id                 as "Port Expense ID",
 port_expense.name::text         as "Port Expense",
 terminal.id                     as "Terminal ID",
 terminal.name                   as "Terminal Name",
 berth.id                        as "Berth ID",
 berth.name                      as "Berth Name",
 object_json.name  as "Data Name",
 object_json.value as "Data Value"
 object_json->>'from'    as "From", 
 object_json->>'to'      as "To",
 object_json->>'unmoor'  as "Unmoor",
 object_json->>'var'     as "Var",
 object_json->>'tariff'  as "Tariff",
 object_json->>'rate'    as "Rate",
 object_json->>'lumpsum' as "Lumpsum",
 object_json->>'max'     as "Max",
 object_json->>'min'     as "Min",
 object_json->>'charge'  as "Charge",
 object_json->>'day'     as "Day",
 object_json->>'night'   as "Night" 
from object_json
;
```